# How to create complex rectangle bitmap with a frame, both with a round angles/corners?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I created a sample badge for the label and I got the problem you can see in the picture. In my opinion, the inner bitmap has cut out the rounded area of its corners in the background rectangle.

Here is my code:

```
fun Bitmap.addBorderAndRoundCorners(borderSize: Int, cornerSize: Int): Bitmap {

    val outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        this.width + borderSize,
        this.height + borderSize,
        this.config
    )

    val rect = Rect(0, 0, outputBitmap.width, outputBitmap.height)
    val rectF = RectF(rect)

    val paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        isFilterBitmap = true
        isDither = true
        color = Color.WHITE
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    val canvas = Canvas(outputBitmap)
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSize.toFloat(), cornerSize.toFloat(), paint)

    // draw source
    paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    canvas.drawBitmap(this, borderSize.toFloat() / 2, borderSize.toFloat() / 2, paint)

    return outputBitmap
}
```

[image]

How can I solve that?

Comment: I would do the white background first and then with another canvas draw on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's an update my function, used C. Hellmann's tipe:

```
fun Bitmap.addBorderAndRoundCorners(borderSize: Int, cornerSize: Int): Bitmap {

    val outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        this.width + borderSize,
        this.height + borderSize,
        this.config
    )

    val rect = Rect(0, 0, outputBitmap.width, outputBitmap.height)
    val rectF = RectF(rect)

    val paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        isFilterBitmap = true
        isDither = true
        color = Color.WHITE
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    val backgroundCanvas = Canvas(outputBitmap)
    backgroundCanvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSize.toFloat(), cornerSize.toFloat(), paint)

    val overlayCanvas = Canvas(outputBitmap)
    overlayCanvas.drawBitmap(this, borderSize.toFloat() / 2, borderSize.toFloat() / 2, paint)

    return outputBitmap
}
```